# In watir I want to click on a link which is not disabled. Randomly the links get disabled depending upon the availability of product size

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

```
<ul id="sizeList" class=" sizes small">
<li class="horizontal size disabledOption" title="30">
<span>30</span>
</li>
<li class="horizontal size" title="32">
<li class="horizontal size" title="33">
<li class="horizontal size" title="34">
<li class="horizontal size" title="36">
<li class="horizontal size" title="38">
<li class="horizontal size" title="40">
<li class="horizontal size" title="42">
<li class="horizontal size" title="44">
<div class="clearFloats"/>
</ul>
```

I want to loop through these tags to select the one which is not disabled at that time.

What I am doing is:

```
for i in 0..9 
    if @browser.li(:class => /horizontal size/, :index => i).exists? 
        @browser.li(:class => /horizontal size/, :index => i).span.click
    end
end
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details about what you are trying to do and where the problem is. For example, can you explain the relevant portions of the HTML? You talk about disabled links, but the HTML does not have any links. As well, can you explain the problem with your code - eg what is the error or unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I would gather all the li elements and loop through them and check each and every one of them. If their class is 'horizontal size disabledOption' then I wouldn't click them. Here's my code -- hopefully it works for you. Good luck :)

```
list = @browser.lis(class: /horizontal size\w*/)

list.each do |li|
  li.click unless li.attribute_value(‘class’).include? ‘disabled'
end
```